# Analysing branches with SonarQube and Multibranch pipelines in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, sonarqube, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

We are trying to get our branches analised with sonarQube while using Jenkins Multibranch pipeline.

SonarQube is detecting the branch name, but code is not being uploaded to it. If we remove sonar.branch.name param, code is being uploaded, but all uploads are being referenced to 'master' branch.

This is our simple JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {

      stage('SonarQube analysis') {
        steps {
          withSonarQubeEnv('xxxx-movil-sonarqube') {
            // requires SonarQube Scanner for Gradle 2.1+
            // It's important to add --info because of SONARJNKNS-281
            sh './gradlew --info sonarqube  -Dsonar.branch.name=${GIT_BRANCH}'
          }
        }
      }

      stage("Quality Gate"){
          steps {
              timeout(time: 600, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                  script{
                      def qg = waitForQualityGate()
                      if (qg.status != 'OK') {
                          error "Se aborta la pipeline debido a que no se superan los umbrales de calidad: ${qg.status}"
                      }
                  }
              } 
          }
      }  
    }
}
```

Does somebody know what is our error?

Comment: What is the SonarQube version and edition you use?

Comment: We use SonarQube Version 7.1 (build 11001) Developer Edition (we need some SonarSource plugins)

Comment: Did you try to set also [sonar.branch.target](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Branch+Analysis)?

Comment: Missing "branch plugin" on your Sonarqube installation ?